# Shallow copying Map and Set objects in javascript without doubling memory on every copy

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am working with a Map data structure and I need to make an exact copy of the existing Map object **without** doubling memory usage.

If I were to use an array or a regular object instead of Map, shallow copies can be used to accomplish this via the spread operator which would allow me to reference the original object in memory and use additional memory as needed (only when any changes are made to the new object).

This is the desired behavior, only with a Map object.

This is what I tried:

```
    const shallowCopy = {
      storage: Object.assign({}, this.database.storage), //copying Map object
      counts: { ...this.database.counts },
    };
```

The above approach seems to result in an empty object and not successfully copy Map over.

Again, the main objective here is to create the equivalent of what would be a shallow copy with a regular object, `let foo = {...bar}`, only I'm using a Map object... after the copy I should be able to call the regular Map functions on the copy.. not sure if this is even possible.

I appreciate any suggestions, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`map.prototype.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) method and pass it to the `Map` constructor to get a shallow copy of the `Map`.

The `Map.prototype.entries` would return an iterator with the `key` and `value` in an array container:

```js
//Sample Data
const childData = {
  name: "john",
  surname: "doe"
};

const data = {
  foo: "bar",
  baz: "foo",
  child: childData
};

//Constructing Map from Object
const map = new Map(Object.entries(data));

//Shallow copying the map object to a new Map object
const shallowCopyMap = new Map(map.entries());

printMapAsJson(shallowCopyMap);

//Modifying the object ref
childData.name = "jane";

//Change is reflected as it is a shallow copy
printMapAsJson(shallowCopyMap);

function printMapAsJson(map) {
  console.log(Object.fromEntries([...map.entries()]));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do we know `new Map(Object.entries(data))`  approach won't double memory usage on every copy?

Comment: Basically this would copy the **object refs**  and primitives into a new `Map` container, so the only memory overhead is the new `Map` container. The object members of the `Map` are not deep copied only their refs are copied over.

Comment: `new Map(map)` would also work here, the default iteration behavior of `Map` is the same as `.entries()`.